# PHP and Javascript JSON.stringify in localstorage and convert it into JS object?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, html

Lets say I have a simple PHP that echo's/prints this:

```
[['Staff', 'somewhere', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ['chinese', 'London', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ['Trade', 'essex', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ['Fare', 'london', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ]
```

I get whatever this PHP echo's on my html page using `AJAX` and stores them in `localstorage` using `stringify.JSON` like so:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "my-php-page.php",
data: dataString,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
beforeSend: function(){},
success: function(data){

localStorage.setItem('mapMarkers', JSON.stringify(data));
}
});
```

I get the AJAX response (data) stored in localstorage and I can see it there being stored.

Now, the next step that I'm trying to do is to get the same localstorage value and use it as a javascript object.

So i went ahead and did it like this in my html page after the localstorage is set like above:

```
var locations = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mapMarkers'));
alert(locations);
```

The issue that I'm having is that when I `alert(locations);` I get `null` in the alert box!

But I can see the localstorage being stored in my browser!

**this is what I see in localstorage:**

**Value:**

```
"\r\n[['Staff', 'somewhere', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ['chinese', 'London', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ['Trade', 'essex', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ['Fare', 'london', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ]
```

**JSON**

```
    0
        "
    "

    1
        "\n"

    2
        "["

    3
        "["

    4
        "'"

    5
        "S"

    6
        "t"

    7
        "a"

etc etc......

        "]"
```

Could someone please advise on this issue as I have been spending over 2 days trying to figure this out with no luck at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Okay, it seems like back to drawing board but i keep updating this question to make it a nice tutorial like for others too:

Okay, so I tried to change my PHP like this:

```
$return_arr = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurants";
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql )){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['location'] = $row['location'];
    $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
    $row_array['type'] = $row['type'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
   }
 }

mysqli_close($db);

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

This prints something like this:

```
[{"id":"1","location":"Fitzrovia","name":"Staff Welfare","type":"indian"},{"id":"2","location":"Soho, London","name":"perfect chinese","type":"chinese"},{"id":"3","location":"Southend-on-sea, essex","name":"Fare Trade","type":"kebab"},{"id":"5","location":"Soho, london","name":"Fare Trade","type":"kebab"}]
```

The first thing I noticed is that I get `{}` instead of `[]`....

Mainly because I need my Javascript object to look like this:

```
   [['Staff', 'somewhere', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ['chinese', 'London', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ['Trade', 'essex', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ['Fare', 'london', 'map-marker-icon.png'], ]
```

*Withdout all the "id":...,"location":.. etc etc.....*

I don't know if I could even use that with {} in my Javascript! So, any advise on that would be grand.

The second thing I did was I changed the AJAX code in my html like this:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my-php-page.php",
    data: dataString,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){},
    success: function(data){

    localStorage.setItem('mapMarkers', JSON.stringify(data));
var locations = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mapMarkers'));

alert(locations);

    }
    });
```

This is what I get in the alert box inside the ajax success:

```
[{"id":"1","location":"Fitzrovia","name":"Staff Welfare","type":"indian"},{"id":"2","location":"Soho, London","name":"perfect chinese","type":"chinese"},{"id":"3","location":"Southend-on-sea, essex","name":"Fare Trade","type":"kebab"},{"id":"5","location":"Soho, london","name":"Fare Trade","type":"kebab"}]
```

I don't think that's even correct since its not a JSON.parse(...); string!

Any advise on how to proceed from here would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the key you are seeing in your local storage ?

Comment: @Bhansa, i see the "mapMarkers" in localstorage.

Comment: @JonStirling, not valid JSON in my PHP?

Comment: I tried taking your data which your php is printing and stored and retrieved from localstorage, did alert working fine.

Comment: http://imgur.com/2gA8nXl

Comment: @Bhansa, that is so strange!!

Comment: check whether you are getting the correct data from the ajax call or not, how you are sending the data, mean what form?

Comment: Look a `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` [In the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) then use `json_encode()` to encode your PHP array/object into a proper json string for sending back to the javaascript